# Eating Giraffe Meat 

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals

Why is it common practice not to eat Giraffe Meat?

Comment: See http://www.zootorah.com/VirtualTour/giraffe.html

Comment: How do you know that this is the practice? Do Jews refrain from this in areas where giraffe meat is plentiful?

Comment: Here's a Mezuzah written on giraffe hide https://www1.biu.ac.il/File/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97-21_3_14.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As By: Rabbi Ari Z. Zivotofsky Ph.D. [explains](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/giraffe/) in detail, there is no reason why not to eat Giraffe meat from a Halachic point of view.

Comment: So as to "why it's not common practice", economics from one perspective or another; plus potentially those who are still halachically nervous -- again, that's economics.

Comment: I have been told that it tastes gamy and does not have that much meat on it.

Answer (score 11):

Because giraffes are an endangered species, and we'd get in trouble if we started killing them.

Comment: Michael Kopinsky, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the out-of-the-box answer! Please consider clicking register, above, to create your account. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features and will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is that it's quite dangerous -- a giraffe can kill a lion with its kick!

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason: giraffes are very expensive, and very likely to be found a teraifah, so it is not worth it, and also tza'ar baalei chaim to kill it if it will probably not be kosher.

Comment: Just because it will probably be a t'reifah does not make it tzar baalei haim to kill it if you want to eat it.

Comment: Even if it's רובא דמינכר that it will be treifah? I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: The Noda Bihuda said that game hunting did not violate the specific prohibition of tzaar baalei chayim per se, as the intent was to kill the animal as directly as possible.  Tzaar baalei chayim is about *tormenting* animals.  But I agree that the economics don't add up.

Comment: Can you source this statistic?

Comment: They can shecht it and sell it to non-Jews if it's a treifa. In some places, your shochtim work in a treifa slaughterhouse, and they only pay for the animals if they're kosher

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers that people say they are both off. The place for Shechting is known it and it is huge. The other answer is there is no market for it put that could be solved with some good marketing (Just look at Sushi).The real answer is to eat something we need a Mesorah that it is Kosher.The **Remah** says it about birds in *Yoreh Deah 82:3*. The **Chazon Ish(Yoreh Deah 11:4-5)** and the **Chochmas Adam(36:1)** extends this to all animals. Therefore the real reason we don't eat is because we have no Mesorah for it.

Comment: It's debated whether the Chochmas Adam means you need a tradition that a mammal is kosher, or simply a tradition whether it's treated as "wild" or "domestic."

Comment: For an informative article about this topic: http://www.kashrut.com/articles/giraffe/

Comment: Shulchan Halevi brings mesorah into account.

Comment: @SimchasTorah If a mesorah is **always necessary** then we would not be allowed to eat turkey.  At some point someone must have decided that this previously unknown bird was kosher without having a mesorah for it.

Comment: @Mike, the need for mesorah on birds is different than the need for mesorah on animals (without taking sides on whether it is required in either case). They have a different underlying reason to require it, so you can't compare.