# Is a Jew able to go hunting?

Tags: halacha, death, animals

What is the Halacha in regard to whether or not a person can go hunting? What have Poskim said on this issue?

Comment: The Noda Beyehuda has a famous tshuva on this.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this tshuva?

Comment: http://www.aish.com/ci/be/The_Jewish_Ethicist_Judaism_and_Hunting.html?tab=y

Comment: A more specific question is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15616

Comment: msh210- Where can I find the place where Rav Moshe says that hunting may be done for pleasure?

Comment: @Bochur613: See my edit to [that answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15619/1535)

Comment: The Nodah Beyehuda is http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1447&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=

Comment: Wow. Thank you all for the fast responses!

Comment: Here it is http://www.daat.co.il/daat/toshba/madrich/baaley4.htm

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/eating-giraffe-meat#comment2236_2075

Comment: Rav Yakov Kamenetsky said a jew should not hunt because we shouldnt behave like Aisav.

Comment: @shlomo Does that include not honoring our fathers?

Comment: ur right i need to add more details. I cant think of it right now.

Comment: @Bochur613 R' Moshe does not say that you can hunt for pleasure. The teshuva refers to the removal of a pest whose very presence impedes כבוד האדם (normal human behavior and dignity).

Comment: Bochur613, just so you know, normally, to ensure someone gets notified of a reply in a comment, you must type a `@` character before his nickname. Like so: `@msh210`. I didn't get notified of your question to me, above. (But getting notified wouldn't have helped, anyway, as I didn't know the answer.) [More info on (as it's called) pinging people.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1589324/jewish/The-Jewish-View-on-Hunting-for-Sport.htm

Answer (score 3):

[Revach](http://www.revach.net/article.php?id=49) explains the Teshuva referenced in the comments above:

> When asked if hunting is permitted for sport the Noda B'Yehuda (YD
>   10) clearly expresses his distaste for this inappropriate question yet
>   nevertheless answers the question on halachic grounds.  He raises the
>   possible issues of "Tzar Ba'alei Chaim" (causing pain to live
>   creatures) and "Baal Tashchis" and rejects them both.  Nevertheless he
>   concludes that it is an extremely inappropriate activity for a Jew and
>   there is an element of issur in it as well.
>
> Hunting is not considered Tzar Ba'alei Chaim for two reasons.  First,
>   anything that provides any benefit for a human does not fall under the
>   issur of Tzar Ba'alei Chaim.  Second it is only assur if the animal is
>   left alive in pain and not if it is killed.
>
> With regard to Baal Tashchis it is only forbidden to destroy something
>   that people would otherwise enjoy.  Since these are wild animals and
>   would continue to roam in the forest it does not constitute Baal
>   Tashchis.  Furthermore since the only possible benefit from wild
>   animals are for their skins, killing them transforms them into
>   something fit for human enjoyment.
>
> While he says that one who truly hunts for his livelihood is certainly
>   permitted to do so, no less that one who slaughters animals for meat
>   and chicken, nevertheless, one who main purpose is entertainment
>   should clearly refrain from such a cruel and inhumane activity.  The
>   only hunters we find in the Torah are Nimrod and Eisav not people we
>   should be emulating.